# editing HTML template

Tags: css, html

I am trying to edit this free template but im stuck with banner. I need to  edit banner so that only image remains and not this red transparent background over it.
Here is the link to the template: http://app-radetic.com/ivanj_t/index.html

and this is css file. I can't find out where in banner section I can change it.

```css
/* Banner */
#banner {
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url("../../images/banner.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  height: 35rem !important;
  min-height: 35rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; }
  #banner input, #banner select, #banner textarea {
    color: #ffffff; }
  #banner a {
    color: #ce1b28; }
  #banner strong, #banner b {
    color: #ffffff; }
  #banner h1, #banner h2, #banner h3, #banner h4, #banner h5, #banner h6 {
    color: #ffffff; }
  #banner blockquote {
    border-left-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
  #banner code {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
  #banner hr {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
  #banner input[type="submit"],
  #banner input[type="reset"],
  #banner input[type="button"],
  #banner button,
  #banner .button {
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff !important; }
    #banner input[type="submit"]:hover,
    #banner input[type="reset"]:hover,
    #banner input[type="button"]:hover,
    #banner button:hover,
    #banner .button:hover {
     /box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ce1b28;
      color: #ce1b28 !important; }
      #banner input[type="submit"]:hover:active,
      #banner input[type="reset"]:hover:active,
      #banner input[type="button"]:hover:active,
      #banner button:hover:active,
      #banner .button:hover:active {
        background-color: rgba(206, 27, 40, 0.25); }
    #banner input[type="submit"].primary,
    #banner input[type="reset"].primary,
    #banner input[type="button"].primary,
    #banner button.primary,
    #banner .button.primary {
      box-shadow: none;
      background-color: #ce1b28;
      color: #ffffff !important; }
      #banner input[type="submit"].primary:hover,
      #banner input[type="reset"].primary:hover,
      #banner input[type="button"].primary:hover,
      #banner button.primary:hover,
      #banner .button.primary:hover {
        background-color: #e2212f;
        box-shadow: none; }
        #banner input[type="submit"].primary:hover:active,
        #banner input[type="reset"].primary:hover:active,
        #banner input[type="button"].primary:hover:active,
        #banner button.primary:hover:active,
        #banner .button.primary:hover:active {
          background-color: #b71824; }
  #banner label {
    color: #ffffff; }
  #banner input[type="text"],
  #banner input[type="password"],
  #banner input[type="email"],
  #banner input[type="tel"],
  #banner input[type="search"],
  #banner input[type="url"],
  #banner select,
  #banner textarea {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
    #banner input[type="text"]:focus,
    #banner input[type="password"]:focus,
    #banner input[type="email"]:focus,
    #banner input[type="tel"]:focus,
    #banner input[type="search"]:focus,
    #banner input[type="url"]:focus,
    #banner select:focus,
    #banner textarea:focus {
      border-color: #ce1b28;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ce1b28; }
  #banner select {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 40 40'%3E%3Cpath d='M9.4,12.3l10.4,10.4l10.4-10.4c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.4c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.4l3.3,3.3c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.9 c0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.4,0.9L20.7,31.9c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.4c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.9-0.4L4.3,17.3c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.4-0.9 c0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.4-0.9l3.3-3.3c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.4S9.1,12.1,9.4,12.3z' fill='rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E"); }
    #banner select option {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      background-color: #111111; }
  #banner input[type="checkbox"] + label,
  #banner input[type="radio"] + label {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    #banner input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
    #banner input[type="radio"] + label:before {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
  #banner input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
  #banner input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    background-color: #ce1b28;
    border-color: #ce1b28;
    color: #ffffff; }
  #banner input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label:before,
  #banner input[type="radio"]:focus + label:before {
    border-color: #ce1b28;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ce1b28; }
  #banner ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) !important; }
  #banner :-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) !important; }
  #banner ::-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) !important; }
  #banner :-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) !important; }
  #banner ul.alt li {
    border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
  #banner table tbody tr {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
    #banner table tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075); }
  #banner table th {
    color: #ffffff; }
  #banner table thead {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
  #banner table tfoot {
    border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
  #banner table.alt tbody tr td {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); }
  #banner .highlights .content {
    background: #111111;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.025); }
  #banner .testimonials .content {
    background: #111111;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.025); }
    #banner .testimonials .content .credit strong {
      color: #ce1b28; }
  #banner > .inner {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease, -moz-transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease, -ms-transform 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3; }
    #banner > .inner > :last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0; }
  #banner h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem; }
  #banner p {
    font-size: 1.5rem; }
  #banner a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    text-decoration: none; }
    #banner a:hover {
      color: #ffffff; }
  #banner video {
    -moz-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
    bottom: 50%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    width: auto; }
  #banner:before {
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 3s ease;
    transition: opacity 3s ease;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1.25s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.25s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 1.25s;
    transition-delay: 1.25s;
    background: #111111;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.45;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1; }
  #banner:after {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ce1b28 0%, #111111 74%);
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    webkit-linear-gradientidth: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1; }
  #banner.small {
    height: 30vh !important;
    min-height: 30vh; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    #banner video {
      display: none; } }
  @media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    #banner {
      height: auto !important;
      min-height: 0;
      padding: 4rem 2rem 4rem 2rem; }
      #banner .inner {
        width: 100%; }
      #banner h1 {
        font-size: 1.75rem;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 0; }
      #banner p {
        font-size: 1.25rem; }
      #banner br {
        display: none; }
      #banner .button {
        width: 100%; } }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #banner p {
      font-size: 1rem; } }
  body.is-preload #banner .inner {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.99);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.99);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.99);
    transform: scale(0.99);
    opacity: 0; }
  body.is-preload #banner:before {
    opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: The red overlay is the `#banner:after` pseudo element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule is creating the gradient overlay, so try removing it

```
#banner:after {
     background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ce1b28 0%, #111111 74%); 
}
```

or adding this:

```
#banner:after {
     background: none!important;
}
```

Should fix it